# can't reconnect via ssh

Tags: networking, ssh, power-management

Pretty sure I'm doing it wrong, but I'm not at home right now and while using an ssh connection to my computer, my connection closed and I can't reconnect. I'm about 90% positive that my computer shut off and I want to know if I can turn it on remotely. I'm running 64-bit Saucy on a Dell Optiplex 970 connected to the internet via Wired-to Powerline directly to a server, which in turn is connected directly to a firewall. It's easy to server hop to get to it, but I can't connect to it directly. Is it at all possible to turn my computer back on using mostly default software? I don't have remote VNC or the remote desktop connection enabled for Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wake on LAN doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan)

I believe the default for Wake on LAN is off, so if you never set it, I dont think you can do anything at this point.

Comment: It's possible. My machine has one of those silly new advanced graphical BIOS with a mouse pointer, but it might not have Wake on LAN capability. Is this something in the BIOS or is it a configurable file in the Ubuntu?

Comment: The BIOS and NIC